# How do I put data into a DB using StringRequest?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am creating an Android app using PHP MYSQL. I want to put the ID and phone number in the DB. But I keep failing. I need help....   not error..

php code

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "------", "------", "------");


    $userID = $_get["userID"];
    $smsNum1 = $_get["smsNum1"];



    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO SMSList VALUES (?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userID, $smsNum1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

---------------android code----------------------

1. mainativity

yjyjtdeyhudydtyrytdhdt

---

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button inputbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inputbtn);
        Button deletebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);

        inputbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText idText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userID);
                EditText smsText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsNum1);
                String id=idText.getText().toString();
                String sms=smsText.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            System.out.print(success);

                            /*if(success) {
                                new CustomConfirmDialog().showConfirmDialog(RegisterActivity.this,"사용할 수 있는 아이디입니다.",true);


                                idText.setEnabled(false); // ID 값을 더 이상 바꿀 수 없도록 고정
                                validate = true; // 체크 완료
                                idText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                                validateButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            }*/

                            /*// 중복체크 실패 (사용할 수 없는 아이디)
                            else {
                                new CustomConfirmDialog().showConfirmDialog(RegisterActivity.this,"사용할 수 없는 아이디입니다.",true);
                            }*/
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                // 실질적으로 접속할 수 있도록 생성자를 통해 객체를 만든다. (유저 ID, responseListener)
                // ValidateRequest.java라는 파일을 만들어야 한다.
                sms1 sms2 = new sms1(id,sms, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(sms2);


            }
                                    }
        );
    }
}
```

---

2. sms1

sms1 used StringReqeust.
This is my first time. It is too difficult.
I do not know why the listener is needed. So I wanted to make it as unaffected as possible.

---

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by User on 2018-02-05.
 */

public class sms1 extends StringRequest {

    final static private String URL = "http://aaaai21018a.cafe24.com/smsAdd.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;

    public sms1(String userID, String smsNum1,Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, URL, null, null);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("userID", userID);
        parameters.put("smsNum1", smsNum1);
       /* parameters.put("userGender", userGender);
        parameters.put("userMajor", userMajor);
        parameters.put("userEmail", userEmail);*/
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

---

I have been worried for a long time. This is my first question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "------", "------", "------");


    $userID = $_POST["userID"];
    $smsNum1 = $_POST["smsNum1"];



    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO SMSList VALUES (?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userID, $smsNum1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: can you print this `$_POST` value? like `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Thanks!I fixed get -> POST. I used POSTMAN to put the data into the DB!    But there seems to be a problem with Android ...  thx!